# Problem accessing app delegate from different classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I am writing a iPhone app with three view controllers, and have made a dictionary in the app delagate: NSMutableDictionary *dictionary; with added property and synthesize.

From my FirstViewController.m i run the code

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Count: %i",[appDelegate.dictionary count]);
```

with no problems at all, and I get the count (which is 4) printed out. But when I try the exact same code i SecondViewController.m (both in the viewDidLoad method) I get a bad access error or a "SIGABRT", even though Xcode seems to find the right dictionary (cause it autocomplete the code when I write it). Both .m files have the "AppDelegate.h" imported.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you releasing the dictionary before moving to second view controller? Or the dictionary no longer exists as it was an auto release object? Bad Access comes when we try to access an already released object.

Comment: No the dictionary is actually never released (planning to fix that later), and I never give it a autorelease neither.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I am guessing:
Often in these cases I find that I have made an error in capitalization. Try seeing if a Build and Analyze (or in XCode 4 Product -> Analyze) turns up any warnings.
Also, it would be helpful if you tell us the exact line that is getting the SIGBART

Comment: It`s the     NSLog(@"Count: %i",[appDelegate.dictionary count]);
that gives SIGABRT. Analyze gives a lot of memory leak warnings, but I can´t see that that´s the problem...

Comment: This gives SIGABRT in SecondViewController.m, but not in FWC.m:    [appDelegate.dictionary count];

Comment: Can you edit the original question and place the code from SecondViewController.m?

Answer (score 0):

When is the dictionary initialized? If you call "count" on a dictionary that hasn't been initialized, you would get an error.

Is it possible that the SecondViewController's method gets called before dictionary initialization and the FirstViewController method gets called afterwards?

One way to check is to replace the "count" calls with this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = appDelegate.dictionary;
if (dict == nil)
    printf("\nDictionary not yet initialized");
else
    printf("\nDictionary ready to count");
```

Or just put a breakpoint after the *dict line and see if it shows a memory address.